# Change from API to randomized list of gifs for discord.js bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot, and i don't want to use nekos.life anymore as an API for my fun commands. I'd like to make a list of gifs and have the bot choose a random one every time. this is what I have right now

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { resolveMember } = require('../../Base/Functions')

module.exports = {
    help: {
        name: 'hug',
        aliases: ['hug'],
        description: 'Get a gif for Hugging someone :eyes:.',
        category: __dirname.split("Commands\\")[1]
    },
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        let victim = message.mentions.users.first() || (args.length > 0 ? message.users.cache.filter(e => e.username.toLowerCase().includes(args.join(" ").toLowerCase())).first() : message.author) || message.author;
        await fetch("https://api.miki.bot/images?tags=hug")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(body => {
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(config.embedcolor)
                    .setTitle("Here's your Hug, ")
                    .setDescription(`${victim} is hugged by ${message.author}`)
                    .setImage(body.url)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter(`© jolyne `, "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/jjba/images/b/bb/Iggy_Normal_Anime.png/revision/latest?cb=20151108101034")

                message.channel.send(embed);
            });
    },
};
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Use an array with random index selection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)